# How to build Postgresql recipe without python in yocto?

Tags: python, postgresql, yocto

When I include `postgresql` to my image, I get python installed to my rootfs which is not intended since I am building an image for 16M flash and python takes up to 15M.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += " postgresql "
```

Since I am using my custom distribution layer I try to use `PACKAGECONFIG` to get `postgresql` not to install python to my rootfs?

```
PACKAGECONFIG:remove:pn-postgresql = " python python3"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The question is the answer. This approach works. However it still takes up to 5M. Yea, I'm swithing to SQLite.